# Views in storyboard appears empty

Tags: ios, xcode, view, storyboard

Yesterday, after not working on this project for some time, I booted up my mac again to continue this iOS project. Unfortunately, all of the sudden, after making a view `fixed` after making it `freeform`, Xcode gave me a `"internal error. Please file a bug report and include /var/........."`. I cleaned the project, but now every view appears to be empty, while there are objects in it. See the screenshot below.
[image: empty views]

Afterwards, I have updated to Xcode 7.2 where the problem still persists within this project. Other projects work correctly.
Better yet, whenever I place a new object, for example the picker view, it shows perfectly.

Thanks for taking the time to answer my problem

Regards,
Riekelt

Answer (score 1):

Try this , I have solved same problem by this way.....

**Storyboard -> Attribute inspector -> simulator size -> Fixed**

Answer (score 0):

Hope you would have fixed it already. I had also faced the same problem and solved it with following fix.

Changing size classes back and forth.  **Storyboard -> File inspector -> Interface Builder Document -> Use Size Classes**(reverting the size class in storyboard to the size class which we designed our views originally).